File "MainMenu.py", line 6, in <module> import requests ImportError: No module named requests.So i type pip install request i got the error
File "MainMenu.py", line 6, in      import requests ImportError: No module named requests.So i type pip install request i got the error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for request
Please help,Termux,POCO f5,android 14

pip install requests (with an s).

Building on what @KlausD. said in the comments, to install the requests library, you need to run:
pip install requests

This should install the stable release i.e. requests 2.32.3. Do note that this release Requires: Python >=3.8.
